# IPT_ALIGN macro not defined in netfilter_ipv4/ip_tables.h

Tags: c, iptables, netfilter

I'm writing a small app to manage iptables rules using libiptc. I have used some sample code from [https://it.bmc.uu.se/andlov/dev/library/Linux/libiptc/append.c](https://it.bmc.uu.se/andlov/dev/library/Linux/libiptc/append.c-save) to get started, but get the compiler error on line 31:

*error: ‘IPT_ALIGN’ was not declared in this scope
         size_t entry_size  = IPT_ALIGN(sizeof(struct ipt_entry));*

I cannot see this macro defined in ip_tables.h, and so suspect that it is deprecated.
The netfilter documentation still refers to it though.

Is there a new way to ensure correct alignment, that replaces this macro?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the new macro may be `COMPAT_XT_ALIGN`. The old `IPT_ALIGN` was just an alias of `XT_ALIGN`, which appears to have been deprecated. (see [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ip_tables.h?v=2.6.35#L294) and [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/netfilter/x_tables.h#L487)). I was not able to find any offical deprecation notice though.